# Apache Pulsar vs Kafka - do consumers pull (poll) messages off the topics?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-pulsar

I know that in Kafka, the consumer pulls messages off the broker topics (pull) ?

I get the feeling that Pulsar works the same way, considering that the [`receive`](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/client-libraries-java/#consumer) method blocks. But I can't find a confirmation. Can someone point me to a reference or correct me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Pulsar's Documentation](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/3.5.1/help/datacollector/UserGuide/Origins/PulsarConsumer.html) clearly explains how message consumption works:

> The Pulsar Consumer origin reads messages from one or more topics in
>   an Apache Pulsar cluster.
>
> The Pulsar Consumer origin subscribes to Pulsar topics, processes
>   incoming messages, and then sends acknowledgements back to Pulsar as
>   the messages are read.

---

Messages can be received from brokers either [synchronously (sync) or asynchronously (async)](http://pulsar.apache.org/docs/v2.0.1-incubating/getting-started/ConceptsAndArchitecture/#receive-modes).

`receive` method receives messages **synchronously**. The consumer process will be blocked until a message becomes available. For example,

```
Message msg = consumer.receive();
```

An **asynchronous** receive will return immediately with a value of type `CompletableFuture` that completes once a new message is available. For example,

```
CompletableFuture<Message> asyncMessage = consumer.receiveAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

In Pulsar [document](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/concepts-messaging/#consumers):

> There is a queue at the consumer side to receive messages pushed from the broker. You can configure the queue size with the receiverQueueSize parameter. The default size is 1000). Each time consumer.receive() is called, a message is dequeued from the buffer.

So broker pushes messages to a queue on consumer side. When the `receive` method is invoked, a message will be dequeued and returned.

Pulsar consumer will regularly send permit request to Pulsar broker to ask for more message when the half of the queue is consumed. This is described [here](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/develop-binary-protocol/#flow-control).

In short, as described [here](https://www.confluent.io/kafka-vs-pulsar/)

> Pulsar also uses a push-based approach but with an API that simulates consumer pulls.